# HashMap: can get value if key is hardcoded string but not if it is a variable

Tags: java, collections

I have a static HashMap < String, Integer > with users' UUIDs and IDs.
It is a static variable of UserBean. Saves a database hit to work that out.

For some reasons, in this circumstance only, I can't get the ID ( value ) for the corresponding UUID ( key )
It all works fine if instead of the String variable, I hardcode the its value.

I have used the same static HashMap elsewhere, without problems. The only difference is that this is in a RESTful service, but I don't think it's the cause of the problem. I am a one man band, so I have to ask here. Spent ages on this, there must be an awfully obvious error here, but I still don't have a clue.

```
@Path ( "/ScanOpenRequests" )

public class ScanOpenRequests 
{
    @POST
    @Produces({"text/xml"})  

    public Response scanOpenRequest ( @FormParam ( "openSessionId" ) String openSessionId ) 
    {
        System.out.println ( "user UUID = >" + openSessionId + "<" );
        System.out.println ( "user ID   = " + UserBean.getOpenSessionIdAndUserIdMap().get ( "61d403dd326c4e2eac223a204ead828d" ) );
        System.out.println ( "user ID   = " + UserBean.getOpenSessionIdAndUserIdMap().get ( openSessionId ) );


        UserBean user = new UserBean();
        user.setId ( UserBean.getOpenSessionIdAndUserIdMap().get ( "61d403dd326c4e2eac223a204ead828d" ) );

        new UserBL().getOpenLessonRequestsUserCanHelpWith ( user );

        return Response.status ( 200 ).entity ( "" ).build ();
    }
```

the printout is this:

```
user UUID = >"61d403dd326c4e2eac223a204ead828d"<
user ID   = 749
user ID   = null
```

Can anybody spot what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The value of `openSessionId` is `"61d403dd326c4e2eac223a204ead828d"` (including the quotes) which is different from the hard-coded value `61d403dd326c4e2eac223a204ead828d`.

Comment: Oh lord, it couldn't get more obvious than that! thanks so much - to you and RealSkeptic. I can't accept it as solved for another 10 minutes, I will do straight away as soon as possible

Comment: Suggested improvement: delete answer and close as typo

Comment: @ThomasWeller - just tried it, can't do because it has answers! Flagged it for moderators' attention.